# I want to run a nested query, where first perform a left join and then pull out data where Volume >= 2 and Date for last 3 months

Tags: sql, databricks

I am trying to run a nested query where I am performing a left join and then form the left join data I am pulling records where Volume > 2 and Date if for last 3 months. I am getting error and would like to understand how I can correct the query and make it work also what I am doing wrong. Will appreciate any help.

```
Select 
(topic_desc as Category, acct_nbr, count(acct_nbr) as Volume, received_dt 
from temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right
LEFT JOIN bob_mir_accounts
ON temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right.acct_nbr = bob_mir_accounts.Account
Where bob_mir_accounts.Account is Null;), topic_desc as Category, acct_nbr, count(acct_nbr) as Volume, received_dt
FROM temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right
where Volume >= 2 AND received_dt >= date_sub(current_date, 90)
group by topic, acct_nbr
order by volume asc;
```

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException: extraneous input '{' expecting {')', ','}(line 3, pos 0)

== SQL ==

```
Select 
(topic_desc as Category, acct_nbr, temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right.count(acct_nbr) as Volume, received_dt 
{from temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right
^^^
LEFT JOIN bob_mir_accounts
ON temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right.acct_nbr = bob_mir_accounts.Account
Where bob_mir_accounts.Account is Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, it's difficult to tell what you are actually trying to do. But just to give you an idea of the correct syntax.

```
Select Category,
       acct_nbr,
       volume,
       received_dt
  FROM (SELECT topic_desc as Category,  
               acct_nbr, 
               count(acct_nbr) as Volume, 
               received_dt 
          from temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right
          LEFT 
          JOIN bob_mir_accounts
            ON temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right.acct_nbr = bob_mir_accounts.Account
         WHERE bob_mir_accounts.Account is Null
         GROUP
            BY topic_desc,
               acct_nbr,
               received_dt
       ) TMP
 WHERE volume >= 2
   AND received_dt >= date_sub(current_date, 90);
```

Comment: this is helpful, what you gave is exactly what I needed help with the layout of the nested query, what is the TMP for?

Comment: The "TMP" is an alias for the subquery. I've never used databricks but a lot of SQL dialects require this.